# Oracle SQL select multiple columns distinct values in one query with pagination requirement for each column based on distinct value

Tags: sql, oracle

My table contain something like below,

> CUSTOMER_ID ATTR1      ATTR2
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      1  V1_0001    V2_0001
>      2  V1_0001    V2_0001
>      3  V1_0001    V2_0001
>      4  V1_0001    V2_0002
>      5  V1_0001    V2_0003
>      6  V1_0002    V2_0004
>      7  V1_0003    V2_0005
>      8  V1_0004    V2_0005
>      9  V1_0004    V2_0005
>     10  V1_0005    V2_0006
>     ..  .......    .......
> 100000  V1_0120    V2_0268
> ```

100000 rows selected.

Is there any way I can select Distinct Values of each column (not using group by listed columns) in one query - also without using UNION?? Customer_Id is not required.

Complexity is that I need to restrict the distinct values count for both columns to (first) 100 records of each column.

In another words my result should be something like,

> ATTR1      ATTR2
>   -------    -------
>  
>   V1_0001    V2_0001
>   V1_0002    V2_0002
>   V1_0003    V2_0003
>   .......    .......
>   V1_0100    V2_0100

Returning null (or no value) for either columns is fine if that column's distinct value falls short of 100.

This is just a small portion of my original query, rest I can manage.
Please help.

Comment: Any point to not using GROUP BY or is it a test of some kind?

Comment: GROUP BY attr1, attr2 gives me a combined grouping result, where as I need individual DISTINCT attr1, DISTINCT attr2 and pick first 100 or lesser of attr1 and pick the first 100 or lesser of attr2. Some times attr1 may have only 50 values, but need to decide on using rownum or rank.

Answer (score 0):

Such requirement never comes, well not perfect but working

```
with tab(ids, v1, v2) as (
select 1,'V1_0001', 'V2_0001' from dual union all
select 2,'V1_0001', 'V2_0001' from dual union all
select 3,'V1_0001', 'V2_0001' from dual union all
select 4,'V1_0001', 'V2_0002' from dual union all
select 5,'V1_0001', 'V2_0003' from dual union all
select 6,'V1_0002', 'V2_0004' from dual union all
select 7,'V1_0003', 'V2_0005' from dual union all
select 8,'V1_0004', 'V2_0005' from dual union all
select 9,'V1_0004', 'V2_0005' from dual union all
select 10,'V1_0005', 'V2_0006' from dual),
tab2 as (select v11, rownum r1 from
        (select distinct v1 as v11 from tab) where rownum <= 100),
tab3 as (select v22, rownum r2 from
        (select distinct v2 as v22 from tab) where rownum <= 100)
select v11, v22
  from tab2
 full outer join tab3 on (r1 = r2)
```

output:

```
V11                          V22
---------------------------- ----------------------------
V1_0001                      V2_0001
V1_0002                      V2_0002
V1_0003                      V2_0003
V1_0004                      V2_0004
V1_0005                      V2_0005
                             V2_0006
```